# How to animate height of transition-group container in Vue

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, transition

I am trying to add and remove items from list. I am able to animate the list but the container's height is not animating.

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-list-container-transition-e5sy6)

As you can see in the preview, the red container gets and lose height without transition.

How can I animate the height of the container as well when an item is added or deleted?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add CSS-attribute to your container : `transition: .3s` where 3s is a value of transition time & change dynamically the height of container.

Comment: What is the best way to handle and set the dynamic height of the container according to you.

Comment: `v-bind` to style attribute i think

Comment: Certainly, for this we have to add max-height, right? For this how do I calculate the height of the element?

Comment: I get it. Look at this example: https://jsfiddle.net/nthk0myo/ Just set the static height for yours added elements.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. It was around my head but I am not sure why I didn't try that.

By the way anyone checking this in future in real World usage I am calculating height of the element using `this.$refs.thatElement.offsetHeight` and adding it to height.

Answer (score 0):

```
<template>
  <div :style="{'max-height': list.length * 24 + 'px'}" class="hgh bg-red-400 container mx-auto">
    <transition-group name="fade-top" tag="ul">
      <li v-for="(item, index) in list" :key="index">
        <p>{{ item }}</p>
      </li>
    </transition-group>
    <button class="mt-4 px-5 py-2 bg-indigo-400 text-white" @click="add">Add</button>
    <button class="mt-4 ml-4 px-5 py-2 bg-indigo-400 text-white" @click="remove">Remove</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  data() {
    return {
      list: [1, 2, 3, 4]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    add() {
      this.list.push(Math.round(Math.random() * 10));
    },
    remove() {
      this.list.pop();
    }
  }
};
</script>
<style>
.fade-top-enter-active,
.fade-top-leave-active {
  transition: opacity 0.3s, transform 0.35s;
}
.fade-top-enter {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(8%);
}
.hgh {
  height: 100vh;
  transition: max-height 300ms;
}
.fade-top-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(-8%);
}
</style>
```

Height transitions are usually done with `max-height`. First you set an big height like `100vh` and at your div you calculate the `max-height` depending on your list length

```
:style="{'max-height': list.length * 24 + 'px'}"
```

If you ask where the `24` comes from, its the height of your `p` element

Also add an css class to your div

```
.hgh {
  height: 100vh;
  transition: max-height 300ms;
}
```

Comment: This is nice but can this be improved? Because `p` tag can't have fixed height in real-world applications. Also, can it be possible without a patch like `height 100vh`?